# Android - telephonyService.endCall() is delayed

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have this following `BroadcastReceiver` class to block incoming calls.

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

if(null == bundle)
return;

   String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);


   String info = "Detect Calls sample application\nOutgoing number: " + phonenumber;

   Toast.makeText(context, info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



   TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   try {
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);

        telephonyService.endCall();

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("error on end call : "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}    
}
}
```

Everything is working as intended but my issue is, everytime there is a delay in `telephonyService.endCall();`. Meaning, I can hear a fraction of ringtone before it gets disconnected. 
 Also, the call disconnected by `endCall()` is not counted as a missed call but as a incoming call. Is this the default behaviour?

Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: You're using functionality that wasn't intended to be used by the designers, so it's no wonder that it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: True that, I'm indeed using reflection to get the telephony method. But is there any way around it? May be using higher number for `android:priority`?

Comment: There is always going to be a delay since your BroadcastReceiver is in user space and the incoming call originates from driver space which handles the network connection -> system space which handles showing the dialer pop up for pickup and notifying the user with a ringtone.